# Consuming https/ssl web service in Mule (CXF)

Tags: ssl, https, cxf, mule

I have this problem consuming a .NET web service over https/ssl in MULE 3.3.0 CE. I hope someone have a good idea to solve this issue.
This works fine out-side of Mule, using CXF library (2.5.1) and the same JRE (7) Mule uses. Then I suppose Mule also uses the jre key store where I have installed the trust certificate.

I have generated the proxy-classes with wsdl2java.
The service uses Web Services Security UsernameToken, profile 1.1. The service and server is out of my controlling (this is a public service).

I know I don't use mule outbound transports to connect to the service. I am simply trying to create and use the service from inside of a java class. Have tried other mule configurations like  but no luck.

This is my mule-config:

```
<flow name="flow1" >
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/server" doc:name="HTTP endpoint"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="ServerResources RESTful service">
            <component class="my.code.ServerResourceImpl"/>
        </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Innside ServerResourceImpl class I do this:

```
service = new xWebService();
port = service.getBasicHttpBindingBalanseWebService();

Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
            reqContext.put("ws-security.username", "username");
            reqContext.put("ws-security.password", "password");

String s = port.test();
```

I can successfully create the service, but my call to the test method fails with this error:
`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message`

Any helpful hints or ideas are appreciated, a lot. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Mule to perform the call? Also where/how do you instruct Mule to load the keystore?

Comment: The reason is that I know Java better than Mule. I have tried letting Mule perform the call, but that brought up new issues. I don't tell Mule to load any keystore. I thought Mule used the keystore from JRE when not specified in Mule. But this might be very wrong. Appreciate any mule-config example for keystore-loading.

Comment: If you'd use Mule HTTPS, that's how you'd configure the keystore: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/HTTPS+Transport+Reference#HTTPSTransportReference-ConfigurationReference